# Data Matching Function in Cloud Firestore with Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

We currently have data that is written to Google Firebase in the following fashion.

Someone/People determines they are 'available' along with additional criteria. Once submitted they are added to a table/store of data.

We need to regularly query this data store for matches. For example, there might be 1000 people/records in this data store/table. We would need to take two records, use the data elsewhere and remove it from that table/store.

We need to do this very often as its a matchmaking/search service. So every second we need to run multiple searches.

How do we ensure concurrent data? As in at any time the same record is not held by the function running searches.

Comment: What do you mean by a record being "held"?  Document reads don't "hold" anything.

Comment: @DougStevenson What I would like to ensure is that in the following example. The matchmaking service/function is called often so it could be running more than once at the same time. If both instances of the service/function pick up the same record from this one store.... I don't want them both to own/move the record. To ellaborate the records will be taken from a waiting place, into a room (like a chat room), the same record cannot be moved into two rooms at once, it should be some what 'held' by the function that is about to move it.

Answer (score 2):

Transactions should work for you.  Transactions are built for this very purpose, to ensure proper processing with concurrent connections or requests.

*Official Reference:*
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#transaction

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty clear. To ensure atomicity you need [Transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#transaction). Rather than using `set()` to update/insert fields you should use `transactions()`, which changes an existing value to new value atomically unlike `set()` which just overwrites data. If at the time of writing your field, any other client is modifying the data, then your or other transactions will keep retrying until it succeeds with the new current value.(It stops retrying only if you abort the transaction.)

Also, as an important note from firebase, Modifying data with `set()` will cancel any pending transactions at that location, so extreme care should be taken if mixing `set()` and `transaction()` to update the same data.